# In Tensorflow Probability, how do I evaluate probability of a multi-batch, multivariate Distribution?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am struggling to understand the broadcasting rules that govern the behavior
of Tensorflow Probability distributions, specifically for evaluating the probabilities of sample points.

Here's what I've got:  First, there is the distribution:

```
tfd.MultivariateNormalDiag("MultivariateNormalDiag", batch_shape=[3], event_shape=[2], dtype=float64)
```

The batch_shape of [3] is because we have three distributions, corresponding
to three different input classes, and the event_shape of [2] is because those
distributions are bivariate, corresponding to the two features that we're using
to predict the conditional probability of the three classes.

Next, there are the input data.  There is an array "data" of 120 two-vectors
corresponding to the feature values of each sample, and an array "labels" of
class labels 0, 1 or 2.  The idea is that we separate the inputs into
three bunches (I'm reluctant to say batches), thus:

```
data0 = [ datum for datum, label in zip( data, labels ) if label == 0 ]
data1 = [ datum for datum, label in zip( data, labels ) if label == 1 ]
data2 = [ datum for datum, label in zip( data, labels ) if label == 2 ]
```

We want to apply the first of the three distributions to data0, the second
to data1, and the third to data2.

Here's where it gets a little tricky:  We have a distribution with a
batch/event shape of 3/2, and the data0, data1 and data2 inputs, which
have shapes (50,2), (40,2) and (30,2).

My question is:  *How do I evaluate the probabilities* for the elements of
data0, data1 and data2?   For example, I can't broadcast (50,2) over (2,3).

Answer (score 0):

A couple things you could try:

1. `Distribution`s support slicing:

```py
d = tfd.Normal([-1., 1.], 1.)

print(d.mean())
# ==> [-1., 1.]

print(d[0].mean())
# ==> -1.

print(d[1].mean())
# ==> 1.
```

So you could do

```py
log_probs = [
  d[i].log_prob(data)
  for i, data in enumerate([data0, data1, data2])
]
```

The result will be a length-3 list of vectors (of different dimensions) of log-probability densities, one for each data point under the given label.

2. Alternatively, you could compute all log_probs under all models (using broadcasting), then use `tf.gather` or (probably) some fancy numpy indexing to get the ones you want depending on the labels.

```py
print(data.shape)
# ==> (120, 2)

broadcastable_data = data[:, tf.newaxis, :]
print(broadcastable_data.shape)
# ==> (120, 1, 2)

log_probs = d.log_prob(broadcastable_data)
print(log_probs.shape)
# ==> (120, 3)

print(labels.shape)
# ==> (120)

# Get the labels[j]'th entry along row j for each j \in (0, ..., 119)
log_probs_by_label = tf.gather(log_probs, indices=labels)
print(log_probs_by_label.shape)
# ==> (120)
```

If you haven't seen it, [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/examples/Understanding_TensorFlow_Distributions_Shapes) is a great guide to shapes in TFP.

HTH!